# Работа кнопок в TKinter на Python в ООП

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, tkinter, button

Такой вопрос.

Попробовал я как то сделать "Лист персонажа" для StarFinder через Python.

Перебрал кучу вариантов и пришел к тому, что через классы проще всего написать и вообще создать нужное мне меню в TKinter. Однако не могу теперь понять. Как при нажатии на кнопки (+) или (-) в меню, добавлять и убавлять значения соответствующих "навыков"? Или как присвоить пустой области необходимое мне значение? Чтоб потом можно было с ним работать дальше.

Я не прошу переделывать весь код, но если сможете хотя бы на коротком примере объяснить, буду признателен.

В идеале при нажатии кнопки (+) на против соответствующего навыка значение должно увеличиваться на 1, при нажатии (-) соответственно убавляться на 1.

И в строках напротив слов Сила, Ловкость и т.д. ввести чисто запись значений через клавиатуру.

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
spec = ['Сила','Ловкость','Выносливость','Интеллект','Мудрость','Харизма']
skills = ['Акробатика','Атлетика','Биологические науки','Блеф','Внимание',
          'Выживание','Дипломатия','Запугивание','Инженерное дело',
          'Компьютеры','Культура','Ловкость рук','Маскировка','Медицина',
          'Мистицизм','Пилотирование','Проницательность','Профессия',
          'Профессия(2)','Скрытность','Физические науки']
player_data=['Имя персонажа','Уровень','Раса','Класс','Тема','Мировоззрение',
             'Имя игрока']

class Data(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        r = 0
        c = 1
        c2 = 2
        self.geometry('900x900')
        self.config(bg='gray35')
        self.title("Лист персонажа")
        self.fr1= Frame(self,bg='black')
        self.fr1.place(x=10,y=10)
        for i in player_data:
            r += 1
            self.lbl = Label(self.fr1, text=i,bg='black',fg='gold').grid(row=r, column=c)
            if i == 'Имя персонажа':
                self.name = Entry(self.fr1).grid(row=r, column=c2)
            elif i == 'Уровень':
                self.ur=Combobox(self.fr1,values=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
                                                 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)).grid(row=r, column=c2)
            elif i == 'Раса':
                self.race=Combobox(self.fr1,values=('Не выбрано','Андроид','Веск','Исок',
                                                  'Касат','Лашунт','Человек','Ширен')).grid(row=r, column=c2)
            elif i == 'Класс':
                self.klass=Combobox(self.fr1,values=('Не выбрано','Механик',
                                                  'Мистик','Оперативник','Посланник','Солдат','Солярион'
                                                  ,'Техномант')).grid(row=r, column=c2)
            elif i == 'Тема':
                self.teme=Combobox(self.fr1,values=('Без темы','Ас','Ксеноискатель','Кумир','Наёмник',
                                                   'Охотник за головами','Покоритель космоса',
                                                   'Преступник','Священник','Учёный')).grid(row=r, column=c2)
            elif i == 'Мировоззрение':
                self.mir= Combobox(self.fr1,values=('Не выбрано','ПД','НД','ХД','ПН','Н','ХН','ПЗ','НЗ','ХЗ')).grid(row=r, column=c2)
            elif i == 'Имя игрока':
                self.pl_name= Entry(self.fr1).grid(row=r, column=c2)
            if r == 3:
                r=0
                c+=2
                c2+=2
        self.fr2 = Frame(self, bg='black')
        self.fr2.place(x=10, y=80)
        for i in spec:
            r += 1
            self.lbl = Label(self.fr2, text=i, bg='black', fg='gold').grid(row=r, column=c)
            self.ent_spec = Entry(self.fr2).grid(row=r, column=c2)
            self.mod = Label(self.fr2, text='  +0',bg='black', fg='gold').grid(row=r, column=c2+1)
        self.fr3 = Frame(self, bg='black')
        self.fr3.place(x=10, y=220)

        for i in skills:
            r+=1
            self.lblskill = Label(self.fr3, text=i, bg='black', fg='gold').grid(row=r, column=c)
            self.lbl_skill = Label(self.fr3, text=0, bg='black', fg='gold').grid(row=r, column=c2)
            self.appskill = Button(self.fr3, text='+', bg='black', fg='gold').grid(row=r, column=c2+1)
            self.subtskill = Button(self.fr3, text='-', bg='black', fg='gold').grid(row=r, column=c2+2)


kvent=Data()

kvent.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть несколько подходов...

1. Работать непосредственно с атрибутами виджетов. Т.е. получать значение из атрибута, скажем `text` у `Label`, при помощи метода `get()`, менять его, и заносить обратно методом `set()`.
2. Создать [Tk-переменную](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#coupling-widget-variables) нужного типа, и проассоциировать её с виджетом при помощи параметра `textvariable=`. Тогда меняя эту переменную, её значение будет автоматически отображаться в виджете. Например, для вашей таблицы навыков, это может выглядеть так:

```
        self.skills_values = {}
        for i in skills:
            r+=1
            var = IntVar()
            self.skills_values[i] = var  # сохраним переменную в словарь чтобы потом можно было получить значение по названию скила
            Label(self.fr3, text=i, bg='black', fg='gold').grid(row=r, column=c)
            Label(self.fr3, textvariable=var, bg='black', fg='gold').grid(row=r, column=c2)
            Button(self.fr3, text='+', bg='black', fg='gold', command=lambda var=var: self.increase(var)).grid(row=r, column=c2+1)
            Button(self.fr3, text='-', bg='black', fg='gold', command=lambda var=var: self.decrease(var)).grid(row=r, column=c2+2)

    def increase(self, var):
        var.set(var.get() + 1)
    def decrease(self, var):
        var.set(var.get() - 1)
```

Для `Entry`, в принципе, делается аналогично. Если нужно хранить текст, то используйте `StringVar`.